# Size of the training set versus complexity of the model during hyper-parameter tuning

Tags: neural-networks, hyperparameter, tuning

In general, the higher is the complexity of a model (number of parameters) the larger should be the training size to try to avoid overfitting. With neural networks, one can have one or more hidden layers and each layer can have a certain number of neurons inside. Choosing the best network architecture is problem-specific and should be decided by cross-validating the different options by parameter tuning.

When doing this, however, we are cross-validating the performance of networks with different complexities while using the same size of the training set. Smaller networks may receive an advantage by being trained with more data per parameter with respect to larger networks.

In your opinion, can this have an effect on the overall result of the tuning process and best parameters choice?

Should we then increase the size of the training set during the tuning process to maintain a similar number of training data points for each parameter (imagine a hypothetical case where we have infinite training data)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is with the theoretical situation where you have infinite training data. If this was possible, then you should use as much training data as possible. Unfortunately, this is never the case. Because of this finiteness, we are restricted.

One way to think of this is that model size *is a hyperparameter*. With this thought in mind, we can intuit that biasing our hyperparameter turning by giving larger models more training data actually undermines our hyperparameter tuning process; if you aren't going to give a larger model more data in the final analysis, why would you give it that advantage now? Because of this, I would suggest keeping your training data size uniform across model size, because the data you have available is also of a finite and uniform size.